# MySQL: Create running sum for all dates in range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Service`, that stores records of sales and referral types that led to the sale. I need to know the total number of sales that resulted from a given referral type over a range of dates. The relevant data in `Service` looks like the following:

```
+------+-------+------------+
| uuid | sr_id | s_saledate |
+------+-------+------------+
|      |     1 | 2020-01-01 |
|      |     1 | 2020-01-01 |
|      |     2 | 2021-01-01 |
|      |     2 | 2021-01-01 |
|      |     1 | 2021-01-01 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

I want to count the number of sales for each referral type (`sr_id`) in a given date range.

If my date range is 2020-01-01 thru 2021-01-01, my output should be something like:

```
+------+-------+------------+----------------------+
| uuid | sr_id | date       | num_sales_as_of_date
+------+-------+-----------------------------------+
|      |     1 | 2020-01-01 | 2                    |
|      |     1 | 2020-01-02 | 2                    |
|      |     1 | 2020-01-03 | 2                    |
........................................................ < many rows for days in range 
             1   2021-01-01 | 3
|      |     2 | 2020-01-01 | 0                    |
|      |     2 | 2020-01-02 | 0                    |
........................................................ < many rows for days in range 
|      |     2 | 2020-01-01 | 2                    |
+------+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

There should be a row for each referral type on each date in the range.

Right now my query looks like:

```
SELECT s.sr_id,
       s.s_saledate               AS date,
       Count(s.uuid)
         OVER (
           partition BY s.sr_id
           ORDER BY s.s_saledate) AS num_sales_as_of_date
FROM   Service s
```

How do I get the running sum for each referral type on days that had no Service with that particular referral type id?
*** EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION***

For example, in the first table I give  there is no Service row in the Service table with sr_id = '1' AND s_saledate === "2020-01-02". There were two rows from prior days where sr_id = '1'. (2020-01-01). My output row for "2020-01-02" is:

```
sr_id  date       num_sales_as_of_date 
  1 | 2020-01-02 | 2                  |
```

Comment: is there a table that lists "each referral type"?  or are they a known set (e.g. 1, 2, or 3)?

Comment: It sounds like you want a sum of 0 for the days with no rows? You need to outer-join with either a calendar table or generate a series of dates for the desired range.

Comment: @Stu and with a table of all the referral types

Comment: I wouldn't want 0. I would want the sum as of that date on days with no rows.

 For example, there is no Service row in the Service table with sr_id = '1' AND s_saledate === "2020-01-02". There were two rows from prior days where sr_id = '1'. (2020-01-01).

My output row for "2020-01-02" is:


sr_id   date             num_sales_as_of_date
  1    | 2020-01-02 | 2                    |

Comment: There is a table that lists each referral type, `sr_id` is a foreign key that points to `ServiceReferral`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to left join your Services table from a table with all the dates in the range and a table with all the referral types, so that you get a row with every combination of date and referral type:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
    SELECT date('2020-01-01') AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dates.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM dates
    WHERE dates.date <= '2020-01-05'
)
SELECT ServiceReferral.sr_id,
       dates.date,
       Count(s.uuid)
         OVER (
           partition BY ServiceReferral.sr_id
           ORDER BY dates.date) AS num_sales_as_of_date
FROM dates
CROSS JOIN ServiceReferral
LEFT JOIN Service s ON s.s_saledate=dates.date AND s.sr_id=ServiceReferral.sr_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hDd34F65)

If you do this a lot, it may be more convenient to create an actual table `dates` with all the dates from 0000-01-01 to 9999-12-31 and use that instead (selecting dates in the desired range in the where clause).